# await HttpClient.SendAsync is not responsive

Tags: c#, http, curl, x509

I have a curl command that returns an output. Access Denied is fine for me, the XML output is what interests me at the moment.

[image]

```
curl -v  -E C:\SEB\certificate.pfx --cert-type p12 -X GET https://test.api.bgw.baltics.sebgroup.com/v1/accounts/EE101010220279354221/current-transactions -H OrgId:22223338
```

I have written a code snippet that should do the same thing as the curl command provided but the response variable returns null (when code reaches line )

```
response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

the program quits and no further code is executed.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I get the contents of the response just like in the curl command?

Thank you for your help in advance

---

```
public async Task HttpRequestAppAsync()
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler {ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual};
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("C:\\SEB\\certificate.pfx"));

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://test.api.bgw.baltics.sebgroup.com/v1/accounts/EE101010220279354221/current-transactions"))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("OrgId", "22223338");
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 1):

Seemed to have figured it out. 
A dead lock was in place
All I needed to do was to add an additional method ConfigureAwait and set it to false

```
response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: The ideal fix for [this deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) is not to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`; it is to use [`async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).